# How to download files on the browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, go, axios

I'm working on a simple project to download videos from the browser using youtube-dl, for study porpuses.

And I was wondering how to download local files (mp4) on the browser using axios. The browser starts the download, but when it finishes, I can't open the mp4 file.

This is my code Go snippet:

```
func download(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    fileName := "video.mp4"

    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
        return
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
    w.Header().Set("Expires", "0")
    http.ServeContent(w, r, fileName, time.Now(), bytes.NewReader(data))
}
```

And this is my JS function, triggered when the user input a text:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'govideo',

  data() { return {
    url: '',
  } },

  methods: {
    postreq() {
      axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8090/download", {
        data: this.url,
        responseType: 'blob'
      }).then((response) => {
        var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
        var fileLink = document.createElement('a');

        fileLink.href = fileURL;
        fileLink.setAttribute('download', 'video.mp4');
        document.body.appendChild(fileLink);

        fileLink.click();
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

There's no problem with the video file, but when I download it from the browser I can't open it.

I'm trying to download the file from my post request, should I do a separate get request for it?

There's something wrong with my code, or I'm missing something?

Comment: Its probably not the cause of your problem but have you wrapped `postreq` in a `method`  property?

Comment: @MuhammadaliJafari yes sir, I messed up pasting the snippet, already fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the method of handle the response in axios.I hope the code could help you

```
validateGrpc() {
   
    axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:8090/download", {
    data: this.url,
    responseType: 'blob'
  })
          .then(response => {
            var blob = new Blob([response.data]);
            var downloadElement = document.createElement("a");
            var href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); //create the download url
            downloadElement.href = href;
            downloadElement.download = "test.mp4"; //the name of the downloaded file
            document.body.appendChild(downloadElement);
            downloadElement.click(); //click to file
            document.body.removeChild(downloadElement); //remove the element 
            window.URL.revokeObjectURL(href); //release the object  of the blob

            //    console.log(response);
          })
          .catch(response => {
            console.log(response);
          });
    },
```

If you use my code to download the file ,you will see the file from the browser.
I have see your code on the github.I think you should put the video.mp4 into the directory `vue-go-study\backend`.Then everything goes well.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately it still doesn't work. Could it be something related to CORS or there's some kind of log/information I can provide that helps?

Comment: Could you show the error? I run the code well in my local computer.

Comment: When I try to open the downloaded file, my QuickTime (I'm on mac, tried VLC as well) says it can't open "video.mp4". Downloading directly through the backend route on the browser, it opens without any issue. The problem seems to be when I download it through the frontend.

Comment: Do you confirm that you have downloaded the file from the axios?I have update my answser.

Comment: Yep, I'm using your code snippet. I've uploaded the code to [Github](https://github.com/leozz37/vue-go-study), if you wanna take a closer look.